# Folder Redirection - Create folder as UPN instead of sAMAccountName - Windows, GPO

Tags: gpo, upn

My IT-admin set up "folder redirection" within our network... So our folders are synced from/to a central-share. Because of some custom programs we did... We need the folder for the user to be created using the user's UPN name, instead of their sAMAccountName. The users actually do login using their UPN name, but for whatever reason, the folder redirection technology creates the folder using the sAMAccountName instead of the UPN name. We can't find any options on how to change it from using sAMAccountName to UPN.

See screenshot below to see what I'm referring to... Where it says "Clair" in the example... We see that value as coming from the sAMAccountName value... We want it instead to come from the UPN value... Is this possible?

[image: GPO screenshot]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I realized it is controlled by the %username% variable which is set from sAMAccountName, and not so easy to change.